# how to interpret the string entered by the user?

Tags: c, string, embedded, ascii, type-conversion

```
int main()
{
printf("Welcome to the temperature control program:\n");
    printf("enter the ascii temperature characters");
    printf("enter the ascii characters of an euipment name with + or - and followed by a integer value");
    printf("type character terminated by carriage return");

    char tbuffer [tbuffer_length];
    printf("enter the temperature value");
    scanf("%7c", tbuffer);
    char *t;
    t = fgets (tbuffer, tbuffer_length, stdin );
    if(tbuffer[0] = 'A')
    {

    }
    if (tbuffer[0] = 'B')
    {

    }
    if (tbuffer[0] = 'C')
    {

    }

return 0;
}
```

In this case, the user enters the string value (for example : char buffer[7]= {'A', '+', '2', '5', '.','5','\r'} ) how to interpret this string as A has equipment A or B has Equipment B, +25.5 has temperature value (I want to convert this temperature value to integer) and carriage return. after interpreting and converting this into integer, I need to send through the interface (I know how to send through the interface). Give me some ideas in interpretation.

Comment: use `==` for Equivalence test

Answer (score 0):

use == operator to compare values

```
int main()
{
printf("Welcome to the temperature control program:\n");
    printf("enter the ascii temperature characters");
    printf("enter the ascii characters of an euipment name with + or - and followed by a integer value");
    printf("type character terminated by carriage return");

    char tbuffer [tbuffer_length];
    printf("enter the temperature value");
    scanf("%7c", tbuffer);
    char *t;
    t = fgets (tbuffer, tbuffer_length, stdin );
    if(tbuffer[0] == 'A')
    {

    }
    if (tbuffer[0] == 'B')
    {

    }
    if (tbuffer[0] == 'C')
    {

    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `scanf("%7c", tbuffer);` should be `scanf("%7s", tbuffer);`.

Also `if(tbuffer[0] = 'A')` should be `if(tbuffer[0] == 'A')`. Same for other `if` statements also.

To convert the string to integer, try the following code,

```
char temp[10];
int dec,frac; 



if(tbuffer[0] = 'A')
{
   i=2;
   j=0;
   while(tbuffer[i] != '.')
   {
      temp[j]=tbuffer[i];
      j++;
      i++;
   }
   temp[j]='\0';
   dec=atoi(temp);
   j=0;
   i++;
   while(tbuffer[i] != '\0')
   {
      temp[j]=tbuffer[i];
      j++;
      i++;
   }   
   temp[j]='\0';
   frac=atoi(temp);
}
```

Now the variable `dec` contains the decimal part and `frac` contains the fraction.

For example, if `buffer[7]= {'A', '+', '2', '5', '.','5','\0'};` then `dec = 25` and `frac = 5`.

Comment: could you please tell me how to compare the temperature value ??

Comment: You can extract the data from the string using my code. But I couldn't understand the purpose A, B, and C. What are they? Please update your question with more data and examples. Also please state the purpose of A, B and C.

Comment: there are three equipments or tasks (A,B,C), so I want to interpret and call those equipments on the other side (nothing but hardware {Aeroflex gaisler hardware}).